# Bibliography is alphabetized but small letters come after capitals

Tags: bibliographies

I have an issue where author names that do not begin with a capital letter (such as de Broglie, von Neumann, etc.) appear in the references after the author names beginning in capitals, instead of at their first letter regardless of its capitalization.

I am using the MNRAS template: [cls](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mnras/mnras.cls) and [bst](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/mnras/mnras.bst).

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}
\begin{document}
\citet{deAuthor}, \citet{Zebra}, \citet{DeCapitalized}
\bibliographystyle{mnras}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

and the refs.bib file has:

```
@article{deAuthor, author = {de Author, Person}, year = {2015}}
@article{DeCapitalized, author = {De Capitalized, Person}, year = {2016}}
@article{Zebra, author = {Zebra, A.}, year = {2017}}
```

The reference list shows "De Capitalized, Zebra, de Author" instead of "de Author, De Capitalized, Zebra".
Just to be sure I checked the journal's [author guidelines](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/pages/General_Instructions#6.3%20References%20and%20citations) but they include nothing to say this is the correct order, and many published papers I checked have it the right way (i.e., "de" with "De" and not at the end).

I originally saw this on Overleaf but I checked on my machine with BibTeX and PdfLaTeX and I get the same result. How do I fix this reordering?

Comment: It's actually quite common to capitalize the first letter in the "von" component of a person's full if the ordering is "voncomponent surname, givenname(s)". E.g., one writes "De Vries, Casper G." if the name occurs at the very beginning of an entry, but also "Casper G. de Vries". The `mnras` bibliography style appears to simply adhere to this widespread practice.

Comment: Possibly, but the BibTeX entries for such papers (generated by ADS) do not include this capitalization, nor have I seen it in any paper's bibliography. Even when such authors cite their own previous work they put their surname prefix uncapitalized.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my comment. There are *many" typographic conventions. I did certain not claim that the convention implemented by the `mnras` style is universal or unique. All I said, then, is that saying that the `mnras`  style is somehow wrong is not warranted.

Comment: It turns out that there is already a [github issue](https://github.com/timj/mn2e-bst/issues/16) on this very point.  I've just poked it (no promises...).